# Returning a custom Python model from a slot?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I'm trying to setup up a details window for a `List`.

I've already set something up where clicking on an item creates a new `Window` with `Qt.createComponent`, and information from the clicked item is passed to this new `Window`. I then try to assign the model of a nested `List` to the return value of a Python function (decorated with `@Slot`). This function instantiates a new custom model (subclassed from `QAbstractListModel`) based on the information passed in, and returns it.

My problem is, when I click on an item to launch the window, it throws this error:

```
file:///home/cassidy/Projects/portmod/portmod/_gui/Manage/PackageDetailsWindow.qml:50: TypeError: Property 'get_local_flags_model' of object Config(0x55907ace9e70) is not a function
```

Here's my Python function. This is stored in a `Config` class that's passed to the QML context as `config`:

```py
@QtCore.Slot(str, result=QtCore.QObject)  # type: ignore
def get_local_flags_model(self, atom: str) -> FlagListModel:
    return FlagListModel(get_local_flags(Atom(atom)))
```

Here's my custom model:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Tuple, Union

from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex, Qt


class FlagListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, use_flags: Dict[str, Tuple[bool, str]]):
        super().__init__()

        self._data = use_flags

    def rowCount(self) -> int:
        return len(self._data)

    def data(
        self,
        index: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex],
        role: int,
    ) -> Any:
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return list(self._data.keys())[index.row()]
        elif role == Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            state = list(self._data.values())[index.row()][0]
            if state:
                return Qt.CheckState.Checked
            else:
                return Qt.CheckState.Unchecked
```

My details window:

```
import QtQuick 6.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic 6.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.0

Window {
    id: detailsWindow

    property string atom

    title: detailsWindow.atom
    height: root.height / 1.5
    width: root.width / 1.5

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10

        // TODO: Don't show if there are no USE flags
        GroupBox {
            title: "USE Flags"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            ListView {
                id: useListView
                clip: true
                model: config.get_local_flags_model(detailsWindow.atom);
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                delegate: CheckDelegate {
                    text: modelData
                    checkState: model.check
                    width: ListView.view.width - 20
                }
                
                ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you register config to qml?

Comment: Before going full QAbstractListModel, I am curious to know if you have considered using marshaling your results via a QVariantList?

Comment: @ניר I used `QQmlApplicationEngine.rootContext().setContextProperty()`

@StephenQuan I didn't know about QVariantLists. What are the benefits over subclassing QAbstractListModel?

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems like you registered `config` instance as a context property.
   This is not best-practice instead use [`qmlRegisterSingletonInstance`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6.2/PySide6/QtQml/qmlRegisterSingletonInstance.html)
2. You tried to "property bind" a `Slot`, AFAIK this is not feasible,you can set the model property when to component is completed. i.e

```js
ListView{
    id: useListView
    Component.onCompleted: {useListView.model = config.get_local_flags_model(detailsWindow.atom);}

}
```

Note that generaly you would have pre-initialized it in the model, but I don't know what is your use-case so it is hard to tell.

sidenote: I see that you use annotations, if you are interested [I have a library](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/qtgql) that [creates slots based on annotations](https://nrbnlulu.github.io/qtgql/helpers/utilities/#slot) (and many other hacks), that is mypy compatible.

Comment: 1. Ah, I didn't even know `qmlRegisterSingletonInstance`. Can I just do something like `qmlRegisterSingletonInstance(Config, "io.portmod".encode(), 0, 1, "config".encode(), config)` and use it the same way? 2. How can I make it a JS function? 3. Oh. I was passing the atom because I use it to set the window title too. 4. Good to know! Your library looks useful! I'll have to check it out.

Comment: @PopeRigby 1. You don't need to encode it but yes, and you'll need to import it in QML. 2. `someprop: function(){return config.get_local_flags_model(detailsWindow.atom);}`

Comment: 1. That works great, thanks! 2. I get this error when I do that: `Unable to assign a function to a property of any type other than var.`

Comment: @PopeRigby You can try the solution I proposed in the edit above...

Comment: I tried your edit, and it just throws `fish: Job 1, 'python $argv' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)` and crashes when clicking on an item in the list. What do you mean by this: "Note that generaly you would have pre-initialized it in the model, but I don't know what is your use-case so it is hard to tell"?

Comment: I.e I have an `Person` model and `Address` model so person would include address model inside it... What is `atom` and where is it coming from?

Comment: @PopeRigby  about the error maybe this is because Python would collect the object since you don't have a reference to it.

Comment: `atom` is just a string. The model takes that string, looks up some information on it, and then sets the model data to a list of that information. How would I keep a reference? Is this even the best way to do this? I feel like I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: @PopeRigby where `atom` is coming from?

Comment: Do you mean how am I passing it to the new window, or how I'm getting it from the Python backend?

Comment: @PopeRigby is that a user input? or something that you know in advance?

Comment: Something I know in advance. I have a ListView of packages that get loaded from the backend. When the user clicks on a package, it opens up a popup, then it asks the backend for a model based on details about this package. The model is created at the moment a new popup is created, because it needs to know the package name.

Comment: @PopeRigby so you could have initialized it upfront and expose another role on your model that returns the "package detail" model?

Comment: Oh, maybe? You can return another model from a role? How would that work with the popup?

Comment: @PopeRigby You sure can! you would just pass the model to the popup and have a `ListView` there.

Comment: Oh that's useful. So I pass the model that represents my list of packages to the popup? How do I set the popup's ListView to use that role?

Comment: yes, you should have another role on the model(for the inner model) and just pass it by reference .

Comment: I see. So I can just set the inner model like this? `model: parent.model.innerModelRole` or something like that?

Comment: Something like this, yeah.